# how to sum file size from ls like output log with Bytes, KiB, MiB, GiB

Tags: bash, awk, ls

I have a pre-computed `ls` like output (it is not from actual `ls` command) and I cannot modify or recalcuate it. It looks like as follows:

```
2016-10-14 14:52:09    0 Bytes folder/
2020-04-18 05:19:04  201 Bytes folder/file1.txt
2019-10-16 00:32:44  201 Bytes folder/file2.txt
2019-08-26 06:29:46  201 Bytes folder/file3.txt
2020-07-08 16:13:56  411 Bytes folder/file4.txt
2020-04-18 03:03:34  201 Bytes folder/file5.txt
2019-10-16 08:27:11    1.1 KiB folder/file6.txt
2019-10-16 10:13:52  201 Bytes folder/file7.txt
2019-10-16 08:44:35  920 Bytes folder/file8.txt
2019-02-17 14:43:10  590 Bytes folder/file9.txt
```

The log may have `GiB`, `MiB`, `KiB`, `Bytes` at least. Among possibile values are zero values, or values w/wo comma for each of prefixes:

```
0   Bytes
3.9 KiB
201 Bytes
2.0 KiB
2.7 MiB
1.3 GiB
```

A similar approach is the following

```
awk 'BEGIN{ pref[1]="K";  pref[2]="M"; pref[3]="G";} { total = total + $1; x = $1; y = 1; while( x  > 1024 ) { x = (x + 1023)/1024; y++; }  printf("%g%s\t%s\n",int(x*10)/10,pref[y],$2); } END { y = 1; while(  total > 1024 ) { total = (total + 1023)/1024; y++; } printf("Total:  %g%s\n",int(total*10)/10,pref[y]); }'
```

but does not work correctly in my case:

```
$ head -n 10 files_sizes.log | awk '{print $3,$4}' | sort | awk 'BEGIN{ pref[1]="K";  pref[2]="M"; pref[3]="G";} { total = total + $1; x = $1; y = 1; while( x  > 1024 ) { x = (x + 1023)/1024; y++; }  printf("%g%s\t%s\n",int(x*10)/10,pref[y],$2); } END { y = 1; while(  total > 1024 ) { total = (total + 1023)/1024; y++; } printf("Total:  %g%s\n",int(total*10)/10,pref[y]); }'


0K  Bytes
1.1K    KiB
201K    Bytes
201K    Bytes
201K    Bytes
201K    Bytes
201K    Bytes
411K    Bytes
590K    Bytes
920K    Bytes
Total:  3.8M
```

This output wrongly calculate the size. My desidered output is the correct total sum of the input log file:

```
0 Bytes
201 Bytes
201 Bytes
201 Bytes
411 Bytes
201 Bytes
1.1 KiB
201 Bytes
920 Bytes
590 Bytes
Total:  3.95742 KiB
```

**NOTE**

The correct value as the result of the sum of the `Bytes` is
201 * 5 + 590 + 920 = 2926, so the total adding the `KiB` is
2.857422 + 1.1 = **3,95742 KiB = 4052.400 Bytes**

**[UPDATE]**

I have update with the comparison of the results from [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) and  [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) and [Walter A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220113/walter-a) solutions that gives pretty much the same values:

```
$ head -n 10 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/ //; s/Bytes//; s/B//' | gnumfmt --from=auto | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s " Bytes"}'
117538 Bytes
$ head -n 1000 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/ //; s/Bytes//; s/B//' | gnumfmt --from=auto | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s " Bytes"}'
1225857 Bytes
$ head -n 10000 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/ //; s/Bytes//; s/B//' | gnumfmt --from=auto | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s " Bytes"}'
12087518 Bytes
$ head -n 1000000 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/ //; s/Bytes//; s/B//' | gnumfmt --from=auto | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s " Bytes"}'
77238840381 Bytes
$ head -n 100000000 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/ //; s/Bytes//; s/B//' | gnumfmt --from=auto | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s " Bytes"}'
2306569381835 Bytes
```

and

```
$ head -n 10 files_sizes.log | ./count_files.sh
3.957422 KiB
$ head -n 1000 files_sizes.log | ./count_files.sh
1.168946 MiB
$ head -n 10000 files_sizes.log | ./count_files.sh
11.526325 MiB
$ head -n 1000000 files_sizes.log | ./count_files.sh
71.934024 GiB
$ head -n 100000000 files_sizes.log | ./count_files.sh
2.097807 TiB
```

and

```
(head -n 100000000 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/Bytes//; s/KiB/* 1024/; s/MiB/* 1024 * 1024/;s/GiB/* 1024 * 1024 * 1024/; s/$/ + /; $s/+ //' | tr -d '\n' ; echo) | bc
2306563692898.8
```

where

**2.097807 TiB = 2.3065631893 TB = 2306569381835 Bytes**

Computationally, I have compared all the three solution for speed:

```
$ time head -n 100000000 files_sizes.log | ./count_files.sh
2.097807 TiB

real    2m7.956s
user    2m10.023s
sys 0m1.696s

$ time head -n 100000000 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/ //; s/Bytes//; s/B//' | gnumfmt --from=auto | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s " Bytes"}'
2306569381835 Bytes

real    4m12.896s
user    5m45.750s
sys 0m4.026s

$ time (head -n 100000000 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/Bytes//; s/KiB/* 1024/; s/MiB/* 1024 * 1024/;s/GiB/* 1024 * 1024 * 1024/; s/$/ + /; $s/+ //' | tr -d '\n' ; echo) | bc
2306563692898.8

real    4m31.249s
user    6m40.072s
sys 0m4.252s
```

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, I have a pre-computed `ls` like output (it is not from actual `ls` command) and I cannot modify or recalcuate it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks, because the original file has a different header. `2020-09-02 18:03:20  275.0 KiB my_file.txt` so I strip other columns out.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: You said you can not recalculate the file. When you (or other persons finding the same question) do have access, you might want to use something like `du -bc $(find folder -type f -name "*.txt" | tail -1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For input like the described:

```
2016-10-14 14:52:09    0 Bytes folder/
2020-04-18 05:19:04  201 Bytes folder/file1.txt
2019-10-16 00:32:44  201 Bytes folder/file2.txt
2019-08-26 06:29:46  201 Bytes folder/file3.txt
2020-07-08 16:13:56  411 Bytes folder/file4.txt
2020-04-18 03:03:34  201 Bytes folder/file5.txt
2019-10-16 08:27:11    1.1 KiB folder/file6.txt
2019-10-16 10:13:52  201 Bytes folder/file7.txt
2019-10-16 08:44:35  920 Bytes folder/file8.txt
2019-02-17 14:43:10  590 Bytes folder/file9.txt
```

You could use a table of units that you'd like to be able to decode:

```
BEGIN {
    unit["Bytes"] = 1;

    unit["kB"] = 10**3;
    unit["MB"] = 10**6;
    unit["GB"] = 10**9;
    unit["TB"] = 10**12;
    unit["PB"] = 10**15;
    unit["EB"] = 10**18;
    unit["ZB"] = 10**21;
    unit["YB"] = 10**24;

    unit["KB"] = 1024;
    unit["KiB"] = 1024**1;
    unit["MiB"] = 1024**2;
    unit["GiB"] = 1024**3;
    unit["TiB"] = 1024**4;
    unit["PiB"] = 1024**5;
    unit["EiB"] = 1024**6;
    unit["ZiB"] = 1024**7;
    unit["YiB"] = 1024**8;
}
```

Then just sum it up in the main loop:

```
{
    if($4 in unit) total += $3 * unit[$4];
    else printf("ERROR: Can't decode unit at line %d: %s\n", NR, $0);
}
```

And print the result at the end:

```
END {
    binaryunits[0] = "Bytes";
    binaryunits[1] = "KiB";
    binaryunits[2] = "MiB";
    binaryunits[3] = "GiB";
    binaryunits[4] = "TiB";
    binaryunits[5] = "PiB";
    binaryunits[6] = "EiB";
    binaryunits[7] = "ZiB";
    binaryunits[8] = "YiB";
    for(i = 8;; --i) {
         if(total >= 1024**i || i == 0) {
            printf("%.3f %s\n", total/(1024**i), binaryunits[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3.957 KiB
```

Note that you can add a she-bang to beginning of the awk-script to make it possible to run it on its own so that you won't have to put it in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

Comment: Thank you! `head -n 10 files_sizes.log | ./count_files.sh 3.957422 KiB`

Comment: @loretoparisi Before totally accepting my answer, I find it a bit disturbing that KamilCuk's answer gets `2306569381835` bytes where my answer says `2.097807 TiB`. Can you just check that my script is doing the correct thing by printing `total` as it is? Does it also print `2306569381835`? For that total, I'd expect my script to output `2.097813 TiB`. It may be so that there are lines in your data that KamilCuk's script is capable of decoding that my script can not.

Comment: uhm...it prints out `2.097807 TiB`. Just to be sure I put it up in this way - https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/c43c605871689822e1d06892af2e4a39

Comment: So the output with `total` was `2.097807 TiB 2306563692842.457520`

Comment: I see. `numfmt` rounds directly which results in 5688992.542480 bytes extra. Mine just sums the floating points up and rounds afterwards. Ok, then I'm ok with the answer as it is.

Comment: Also adding that I get don't get any error running the updated code. Also just to remark that this solution is also the faster one (~1,5x faster in comparison to the others).

Answer (score 7):

Use `numfmt` to convert those numbers.

```
cat <<EOF |
2016-10-14 14:52:09    0 Bytes folder/
2020-04-18 05:19:04  201 Bytes folder/file1.txt
2019-10-16 00:32:44  201 Bytes folder/file2.txt
2019-08-26 06:29:46  201 Bytes folder/file3.txt
2020-07-08 16:13:56  411 Bytes folder/file4.txt
2020-04-18 03:03:34  201 Bytes folder/file5.txt
2019-10-16 08:27:11    1.1 KiB folder/file6.txt
2019-10-16 10:13:52  201 Bytes folder/file7.txt
2019-10-16 08:44:35  920 Bytes folder/file8.txt
2019-02-17 14:43:10  590 Bytes folder/file9.txt
2019-02-17 14:43:10  3.9 KiB  folder/file9.txt
2019-02-17 14:43:10  2.7 MiB folder/file9.txt
2019-02-17 14:43:10  1.3 GiB folder/file9.txt
EOF
# extract 3rd and 4th column
tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 |
# Remove space, remove "Bytes", remove "B"
sed 's/ //; s/Bytes//; s/B//' |
# convert to numbers
numfmt --from=auto |
# sum
awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
```

outputs the sum.

Comment: `numfmt` is great so you get my vote. I don't understand why `K = 1000` in `numfmt` though. `k = 1000` and `K = 1024` in my book.

Comment: Thanks, since I'm on `macOS` I had to replace `numfmt `with `gnumfmt`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Infact I get different sizes: `3.957422 KiB` from your script; `4053` from this one.

Comment: @loretoparisi For the input given in KamilCuk's script, my code says `1.302644 GiB`. KamilCuk's says `1398703575` which is `1.3026442145 GiB` - so I think they count the same.

Comment: I think you need to add option `--from=iec`, try `echo 1K | numfmt --from=si` and `echo 1K | numfmt --from=iec`.

Comment: Thanks. They are both correct in fact. I have updated the answer. There is just an approx error from `4052.400` to `4053` in @KamilCul answer.

Comment: @WalterA The `iec` option won't work to make `1K = 1024` since it'll also make `1M = 1048576` and `1G = 1073741824`. Since `K` isn't even in conflict with the SI units, I don't get why they use 1000 for it.

Comment: `--from=auto` detects it. The suffix is `Ki` with an `i`, so it detects it's 1024. You may remove the `i` suffix as well, and use `--from=iec` or `--from=si` depending if you want `1024` or `1000`.

Comment: @KamilCuk `echo 1K | numfmt --from=auto` and `echo 1K | numfmt --from=si`  makes it print `1000` in both cases which doesn't make sense since `K` doesn't exist in SI (except when talking about _kelvin_). Capital `K` was invented just for this case. Is it possible to get `numfmt` to print `1024` for `K` and `1000` for `k`? In fact, I can't find one mode that accepts lowercase `k` at all - not even `auto` or `si`, which is really odd.

Comment: I just downloaded the source and found that `numfmt` doesn't seem to recognize `k` at all... I was about to write a bug report but read their "gothas" page first. It says: "_In general the units representations in coreutils are unfortunate, but an accident of history. POSIX species `k` and `b` to mean 1024 and 512 respectively. Standards wise `k` should really mean 1000 and `K` 1024. Then extending from that we now have (which we can't change for compatibility reasons): k=K=kiB=KiB=1024_" - Bummer :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the input before sending them to `bc`:

```
echo "0   Bytes
3.9 KiB
201 Bytes
2.0 KiB
2.7 MiB
1.3 GiB" |
   sed 's/Bytes//; s/KiB/* 1024/; s/MiB/* 1024 * 1024/; 
        s/GiB/* 1024 * 1024 * 1024/; s/$/ + /'  |
   tr -d '\n' | 
   sed 's/+ $/\n/' |
   bc
```

When your `sed` doesn't support `\n`, you can try replacing the '\n' with a real newline like

```
sed 's/+ $/
/'
```

or add an `echo` after parsing (and move part of the last `sed` into the first command for removing the last `+`)

```
(echo "0   Bytes
3.9 KiB
201 Bytes
2.0 KiB
2.7 MiB
1.3 GiB" | sed 's/Bytes//; s/KiB/* 1024/; s/MiB/* 1024 * 1024/;
s/GiB/* 1024 * 1024 * 1024/; s/$/ + /; $s/+ //'  | tr -d '\n' ; echo) | bc
```

Comment: thanks if I do `head -n 10 files_sizes.log | awk '{print $3,$4}' | sed 's/Bytes//; s/KiB/* 1024/; s/MiB/* 1024 * 1024/; s/GiB/* 1024 * 1024 * 1024/; s/$/ + /' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/+ $/\n/' | bc` I get `(standard_in) 1: parse error`

Comment: Does it work with my `echo` above? Another try: remove the last part `| bc` and look at the string that you see. You are hoping for something like `0    + 3.9 * 1024 + 201  + 2.0 * 1024 + 2.7 * 1024 * 1024 + 1.3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`, strange things need to be settled ("sed-ded").

Comment: okay, without `bc` I can see `0  + 201  + 201  + 201  + 411  + 201  + 1.1 * 1024 + 201  + 920  + 590  n`. Please note I'm on `macOS`.

Comment: Edited my solution.

Comment: now I get `head -n 10 files_sizes.log | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4 | sed 's/Bytes//; s/KiB/* 1024/; s/MiB/* 1024 * 1024/;s/GiB/* 1024 * 1024 * 1024/; s/$/ + /; $s/+ //' | tr -d '\n' ; echo | bc
0  + 201  + 201  + 201  + 411  + 201  + 1.1 * 1024 + 201  + 920  + 590`

Comment: You need the `()` around the input, like `(head -n .... echo) | bc`.

Answer (score 2):

Very good idea from @KamilCuk to [make use of `numfmt`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63859274). Based on his answer, here is an alternative command which uses a single awk call wrapping `numfmt` with a [two-way pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO). It requires a recent version of GNU awk (ok with 5.0.1, unstable with 4.1.4, not tested in between).

```
LC_NUMERIC=C gawk '
    BEGIN {
        conv = "numfmt --from=auto"
        PROCINFO[conv, "pty"] = 1
    }
    {
        sub(/B.*/, "", $4)
        print $3 $4 |& conv
        conv |& getline val
        sum += val
    }
    END { print sum }
' input
```

**Notes**

- `LC_NUMERIC=C` (bash/ksh/zsh) is for portability on systems using a non-english locale.
- `PROCINFO[conv, "pty"] = 1` lets have the output of `numfmt` flushed on each line (to avoid a dealock).

Comment: Good solution, please check the catch by [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) about `k` and `K` in `numfmt`. Also, for `macOS` we have to replace `numfmt` with `gnumfmt`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a better way to work with `ls`: don't use it as a command, but as a `find` switch:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -ls
```

This returns file sizes in a uniform unity, as explained in `find`'s manpage, which makes it far easier to do calculations on.

Good luck

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in the question but in a comment that the output is not from `ls` itself. It's a pre-computed `ls` like output (not from the actual `ls` command) and OP cannot modify or recalcuate it